# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc on RHEL 6

Tags: gcc, rhel6

I am compiling some libraries which tries to check for gcc "-static" option as shown below. In RHEL6 this fails as "cannot find -lc".

```
[root@ ]# echo 'main(){return(0);}' > conftest.c
[root@ ]# gcc -o conftest -g -O2   -static conftest.c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
[root@ ]#
```

I could not find libc.a available in the system.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the `glibc-static` package.

Comment: had to download it from external site since "yum install glibc-static" did not find the package.